# Reverse jquery object

Tags: jquery, object

Jquery Object

```
{"2":"text1", "5":"text2", "3":"text3"}
```

I need to reverse it like -

```
{"3":"text3", "5":"text2", "2": "text1"}
```

What is the optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? While the order of properties in an object can potentially be amended, a far better and more reliable solution would be to use an array of objects, `[{"2":"text1" }, { "5":"text2" }, { "3":"text3" }]` which you can then `reverse()` or `sort()` as required.

Comment: You will find your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order